# XSL does not enter the correct condition

Tags: sharepoint-designer, xslt

I have the following condition (I removed some items not to let the long code):

```
<xsl:when test="$Rows[1]/@Style='Results-List'">
   <ul>
      <xsl:for-each select="$Rows">
         <li>
            <a href="/{@FileRef}" title="{$Data} - {@Title}">
               <xsl:choose>
                 <xsl:when test="(@PublishingRollupImage = '')">
                   <img src="/Util/Imagens/image-test.jpg" />
                 </xsl:when>
                 <xsl:otherwise>
                   <xsl:value-of select="@PublishingRollupImage"  />
                 </xsl:otherwise>
               </xsl:choose>
            </a>
         </li>
      </xsl:for-each>
   </ul>
</xsl:when>
```

In one of the results `@PublishingRollupImage` field is filled, but always in the first condition.

I use a list of pages sharepoint for searching and the column is of type "Publishing Image"

I've tried to do with `xsl:if` however, believe that I'm doing the wrong condition. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Your condition looks correct if you want to implement some kind of default behavior if `@PublishingRollupImage` is an empty string (or does not exist at all). You don't need the parentheses, though. Are you sure that the attribute `@PublishingRollupImage` is in the current node when the condition is being tested? Another thing: in one case you return a string in the other case you return a HTML fragment. Is this intentional? Could you extend your example by adding the embracing tags using the result of your `<choose>` environment?

Comment: Yes it is intentional on a result you see a string and a variable into another come. I added in the variable @PublishingRollupImage and returns the value. But the column is filled. I'll update the example to see if improvements in understanding

Comment: The use of the `<choose>` is much clearer now, thank you. After Googling a bit I think the problem is with the column itself. It appears that the value passed to you is not a string but has some kind of object substructure. I'm not familiar with SharePoint at all (only with XSLT :-) ) but does this help you in any way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/977127/in-moss-can-you-add-a-publishing-image-field-to-an-announcements-list ?